# When user click in a row (dataTable), don't select row

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I'm making my term papper and I need some help with [Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/). I'm using JSF 2.0 and Primefaces 4.0.

The default [PrimeFace DataTable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableHome.jsf) is awesome, because we can get the object of the selected row, thing that I think we can't do in pure JSF.

But I have one problem, I want that user can't select a row, just click in a row. I mean, when the user click in a row, I get the value of the clicked row and this must have a link.

**You understand better when you see my code below:**

```
<p:dataTable id="minhaTabela" var="disciplina" value="#{disciplinaMBean.listaDisciplinasPesquisadas}" rowKey="#{disciplina.id}"                       
selection="#{disciplinaMBean.disciplinaSelecionada}" selectionMode="single">

    <p:column headerText="Nome" styleClass="pull-left">
        <a class="various fancybox.ajax" href="edit.jsf">
                     #{disciplina.nome}
        </a>    
    </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

As you can see, I want that when user click in a row he will redirected to "edit.jsf" (really, this just opens a modal with jQuery). So, what I need is:

1. When user click in a row, the row don't be selected.
2. The row must have a link or something like that, that have a class "various fancybox.ajax" and a link.

**So, there's a way to do that with PrimeFaces dataTable? How can I solve this issue?**

### Edit

This is my new code, similar to @raylee answer:

```
<p:dataTable tableStyleClass="table table-hover" var="disciplina" value="#{disciplinaMBean.listaDisciplinasPesquisadas}" rowKey="#{disciplina.id}" selection="#{disciplinaMBean.disciplinaSelecionada}" selectionMode="single" emptyMessage="Nenhuma disciplina encontrada." >

    <p:column headerText="Nome" styleClass="pull-left">
        <p:lightBox iframe="true" width="100%" height="100%">

            <h:outputLink value="edit.jsf">
                <h:outputText value="#{disciplina.nome}" />
            </h:outputLink>

            <f:facet name="inline">
                <p:panel header="Editar disciplina">
                    <ui:include src="edit.xhtml" />
                </p:panel>
            </f:facet>  

        </p:lightBox>
     </p:column>
     <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{disciplinaMBean.limparSelecionadosDataTable}"/>

</p:dataTable>
```

The `event="rowSelect"`, closer to the last line, just remove all selected rows (I don't want that when user click, the row be selected, and this is the way I found to fix that, because PrimeFaces don't give us a attribute to "selectOrClickRow" - I'm waiting for a feature like that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using PrimeFaces lightbox. This is all the code you need.  No jQuery or manually defining a dialog box.  Notice the dataTable has no selection attribute so the user cannot select a row.

**This is all you need:**

```
<p:dataTable var="report" value="#{tab.reports}" 
    resizableColumns="true" paginator="true" rows="30">

    <p:column headerText="Title" width="20%">

        <p:lightBox iframe="true" width="100%" height="100%">

            <h:outputLink value="#{report.URL}" title="#{report.title}">

                <h:outputText value="#{report.title}" />

            </h:outputLink>

        </p:lightBox>

    </p:column>

    ...

</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Thanks, but with this code I can get the "selected" (clicked) objected? And what `rendered="#{ tab['class'].simpleName eq 'ReportListTab'}"` do? It seems strange to me :/

Comment: Sorry. I should have taken out the rendered. I have actually 2 dataTables on the page.  The one I'm showing here is only rendered when the class name is ReportListTab.  The tabs list is actually a list of abstract classes called Tab.  They can be ReportListTab or ReportObject.  When the tab is a ReportListTab, it lists the reports and come clicks the report as above to load it (what's shown in the lightBox is a BIRT report).  When the tab is ReportObject report data is printed out (a customized report).  tab['class'].simpleName is akin to tab.getClass().getSimpleName() in Java code.

Comment: I'm using your answer in my project, I'll give you the best answer, but can you help me? Your code is good, but for me this don't work for entire row. It just works when I click above the text, but I want that when I click in any part of the row, show the lightbox. I'll update my question with my new code. thanks!